# Cypher query for multiple relationships if either one is valid

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My graph is set up like this:

```
(:User)-[:LIVES_IN_COUNTRY]->(:Country)
(:User)-[:LIVES_IN_STATE]->(:State)
(:User)-[:LIVES_IN_CITY]->(:City)
```

I'm trying to build a dynamic cypher query to check all relationships but return results from only those that are valid

For e.g if I only know Country name and state name, in that case I only pass valid names for country and state and "Not Available" for city. I have tried something like this:

```
Match(n:User)
Match(n)-[:LIVES_IN_COUNTRY]->(:Country {name:'Canada'})
Match(n)-[:LIVES_IN_STATE]->(:State {name:'Ontario'}) 
Match(n)-[:LIVES_IN_CITY]->(:City {name:'Not Available'})
```

But, in this case, nothing is returned. How can I get users for Canada and Ontario in this case when City name is unavailable?

Perhaps it is possible using seperate cypher queries but I was wondering if it possible to handle within one cypher query

I have tried to use optional but it returns all users in all countries, states and so on. Not sure if it is possible with optional or something wrong in query

```
Match(n:User) 
OPTIONAL Match (n)-[:LIVES_IN_COUNTRY]->(:Country{name:'Canada'}) 
OPTIONAL Match (n)-[:LIVES_IN_STATE]->(:State {name:'Ontario'}) 
OPTIONAL Match (n)-[:LIVES_IN_CITY]->(:City {name:'Not Available'}) 
Return n.username,n.country, n.state, n.city
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [OPTIONAL MATCH](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/optional-match/) instead of MATCH for country, state, and city. This will handle non-matches without eliminating the row from your results.

EDIT

I missed that this was a general query, not one where you were querying from a specific user.

I think the best approach would be to leave off matches entirely when the data isn't available (if you're assembling the query from Java or another language).

But if you can't do that, there is another approach we can use.

First, I would change your relationship types to just :LIVES_IN, that will let us do some easier matching later.

The approach for this one is to first use OPTIONAL MATCHes on country, state, and city, then collect these into a single list (removing null nodes where the data isn't available), then perform matching to a person where that same person has a :LIVES_IN relationship to all nodes in the collection.

```
WITH {country:'Canada', state:'Ontario', city:'Not Available'} as params
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Country{name:params.country})
OPTIONAL MATCH (s:State{name:params.state})
OPTIONAL MATCH (ci:City{name:params.city})
WITH FILTER(loc in [c, s, ci] WHERE loc IS NOT null) as locations
WITH locations, LAST(locations) as place
MATCH (n:User)-[:LIVES_IN]->(place)
WHERE ALL(loc in locations WHERE (n)-[:LIVES_IN]->(loc))
RETURN n
```

Rather than match on all users then perform the WHERE ALL, we instead narrow our potential set of users to those who live in the narrowest location, if available (city, then state, then country).

EDIT - extending the query to other nodes/relationships

A warning for the above query, it does require at least one location to be present (country, state, or city). If none of these are available, then the query will fail. If you need to account for this possibility, let me know in the comments.

As far as extending this with other nodes and different relationships, it's possible, but it does require a bit more thought to figure out the approach. It helps if several things fall into the same type, and if all things of a type are represented in the db by nodes of the same label.

In your example of sports, you would most likely pass in a list of sport names for the query, and you'd have several :Sports nodes for each sport.

A modified query might look like:

```
WITH {country:'Canada', state:'Ontario', city:'Not Available', sports:['Hockey', 'Karate']} as params
WITH params, [(s:Sport)-[*0]-() WHERE s.name in params.sports | s] as sports
// keep the location section of your query the same
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Country{name:params.country})
OPTIONAL MATCH (s:State{name:params.state})
OPTIONAL MATCH (ci:City{name:params.city})
WITH sports, FILTER(loc in [c, s, ci] WHERE loc IS NOT null) as locations
WITH sports, locations, LAST(locations) as place
MATCH (n:User)-[:LIVES_IN]->(place)
WHERE ALL(loc in locations WHERE (n)-[:LIVES_IN]->(loc))
// now do additional filtering on sports played
AND ALL(sport in sports WHERE (n)-[:PLAYS]->(sport))
RETURN n
```

The most complicated part is the pattern comprehension (only available in Neo4j 3.1 and up) on the second line:

```
[(s:Sport)-[*0]-() WHERE s.name in sports | s] as sports
```

While it would have been easier to use `(s:Sport)` on its own, Cypher doesn't recognize that as a pattern, so we have to fool it by using a pattern of a 0-length relationship (the node matched is only to itself).

The reason for this is it takes your list parameter of sports names and gives you back a list of associated :Sports nodes.

If you pass in an empty list for sports, this pattern comprehension will result in an empty list, and you can continue the query.

If we had tried a different approach, UNWINDing your list into sports name rows (with the intent to match :Sports with those names), if performed on an empty list it would have resulted in no rows, which would prevent the query from executing any further.

EDIT - all fields optional

All fields being optional imposes an efficiency problem.

In my query, I match on users in some location, using the smallest geographic location possible for matching. This is helpful in that the filtering down of :Users at this level is a constant-time operation, as we don't actually have to inspect ALL users and filter, we just follow the relationship from the location to the relevant set of users. With each subsequent matching or filtering, the set of matched users continues to fall, which is good for efficiency.

But if no locations are in the collection, the match and the query will fail. If I use an OPTIONAL MATCH instead, I'll get a null, which will be useless for reuse on the rest of the pattern matches.

The only way around is to match against all :Users first, and then filter from the entire set of users, so the performance of your queries will be impacted by and slow down as the number of :User nodes grows. As long as every field is optional, with no reliable starting place to match to users, there may be no way around this.

```
WITH {country:'Canada', state:'Ontario', city:'Not Available', sports:['Hockey', 'Karate']} as params
WITH params, [(s:Sport)-[*0]-() WHERE s.name in params.sports | s] as sports
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Country{name:params.country})
OPTIONAL MATCH (s:State{name:params.state})
OPTIONAL MATCH (ci:City{name:params.city})
WITH sports, FILTER(loc in [c, s, ci] WHERE loc IS NOT null) as locations
// now start matching using the set of all :Users
MATCH (n:User)
WHERE CASE WHEN SIZE(locations) <> 0 THEN
    ALL(loc in locations WHERE (n)-[:LIVES_IN]->(loc))
  ELSE true END
// now do additional filtering on sports played
AND CASE WHEN SIZE(sports) <> 0 THEN 
    ANY(sport in sports WHERE (n)-[:PLAYS]->(sport))
  ELSE true END
RETURN n
```

EDIT - case statements to help with optional parameters

I realized that the query I gave will fail if there are no locations, or no sports passed in (due to the ALL() function on an empty list, which will be false), so I edited the above query to use CASE statements to only perform those evaluations if the collections aren't empty.

I also changed the function for sports from ALL() to ANY(), to meet your requirement to return users who play any of the sports given, rather than users who play all of the sports given.

EDIT - Adding properties handling.

If we want to get user between age of 18 and 30, we can add further filtering

```
WITH {country:'Canada', state:'Ontario', city:'Not Available', sports:['Hockey', 'Karate'], ageMin:18, ageMax:25} as params
WITH params, [(s:Sport)-[*0]-() WHERE s.name in params.sports | s] as sports
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Country{name:params.country})
OPTIONAL MATCH (s:State{name:params.state})
OPTIONAL MATCH (ci:City{name:params.city})
WITH sports, FILTER(loc in [c, s, ci] WHERE loc IS NOT null) as locations, params.ageMin as ageMin, params.ageMax as ageMax
// now start matching using the set of all :Users
MATCH (n:User)
WHERE CASE WHEN SIZE(locations) <> 0 THEN
    ALL(loc in locations WHERE (n)-[:LIVES_IN]->(loc))
  ELSE true END
// now do additional filtering on sports played
AND CASE WHEN ageMin <> 0 THEN
    n.age >= ageMin
  ELSE true END
AND CASE WHEN ageMax <> 0 THEN
    n.age <= ageMax
  ELSE true END 
AND CASE WHEN SIZE(sports) <> 0 THEN 
    ANY(sport in sports WHERE (n)-[:PLAYS]->(sport))
  ELSE true END
RETURN n
```

EDIT

Your original requirement was that you would be passing in valid place names or "Not Available", but let's see what we can do to be able to handle invalid place names, but still retain proper behavior with "Not Available".

To help us out, let's create an `:Invalid` node that we'll use to "spike" our locations to prevent any further matching.

```
CREATE (:Invalid)
```

Now we'll do an OPTIONAL MATCH on the :Invalid node and include it in the locations, but we'll add a predicate on it so it will only be matched when one of the city, country, or state OPTIONAL MATCHES fails, but the associated parameter isn't 'Not Applicable'.

In the case where you try to OPTIONAL MATCH to 'Alberta' for the state but the node doesn't exist, then the variable for the state node will be null, and since the associated parameter isn't 'Not Applicable', the :Invalid node will be present in the location list, and will prevent any person from matching (since if the location list is non-empty, persons must have :LIVES_IN relationships to all elements of the list)

```
WITH {country:'Canada', state:'Ontario', city:'Not Available', sports:['Hockey', 'Karate'], ageMin:18, ageMax:25} as params
WITH params, [(s:Sport)-[*0]-() WHERE s.name in params.sports | s] as sports
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Country{name:params.country})
OPTIONAL MATCH (s:State{name:params.state})
OPTIONAL MATCH (ci:City{name:params.city})
OPTIONAL MATCH (inv:Invalid)
 WHERE (c is null AND params.country <> 'Not Available') OR
       (s is null AND params.state <> 'Not Available') OR
       (ci is null AND params.city <> 'Not Available')
WITH sports, FILTER(loc in [c, s, ci, inv] WHERE loc IS NOT null) as locations, params.ageMin as ageMin, params.ageMax as ageMax
// now start matching using the set of all :Users
MATCH (n:User)
WHERE CASE WHEN SIZE(locations) <> 0 THEN
    ALL(loc in locations WHERE (n)-[:LIVES_IN]->(loc))
  ELSE true END
// now do additional filtering on sports played
AND CASE WHEN ageMin <> 0 THEN
    n.age >= ageMin
  ELSE true END
AND CASE WHEN ageMax <> 0 THEN
    n.age <= ageMax
  ELSE true END 
AND CASE WHEN SIZE(sports) <> 0 THEN 
    ANY(sport in sports WHERE (n)-[:PLAYS]->(sport))
  ELSE true END
RETURN n
```

Comment: I should have put that in the question. I have tried that already but it doesn't give correct results. OPTIONAL MATCH would return results for all the countries and all states and so on.

Comment: I have added optional query I tried to the question. Not sure if there is something wrong with how I wrote it

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. But is this query extendable? For e.g If I want to include more relationships - like if User play Sports:Hockey. I know you mentioned one option is to do pre-processing and leave off matches entirely when the data isn't available. But I'm afraid it will be not be an easy task if you have 15 fields. To cover all the combination could result in dozens of queries. Maybe, this could be another question but I'm just wondering if I need to model differently or I made a wrong choice in choosing graph db.

Comment: Edited to add thoughts on extending the query.

Comment: Great! Also, yes, all fields are optional. so, I do need to consider the case where neither country,state, city is present

Comment: I edited my answer with my thoughts on that, and a query that will work with that restriction. Keep in mind that all fields being optional will impact your query, as it means there's no way to quickly get a smaller starting set of :Users, so the first filtering operation must filter down considering all :User nodes.

Comment: I'm getting this error - Invalid input 'W': expected whitespace, comment, a relationship pattern.. and it is pointing at WHERE in - "WITH params, [(s:Sport)-[*0]-() WHERE s.name in params.sports] as sports"..

Comment: There was a bug in there (just fixed it in my answer) where I forgot the `| s` at the end to use the nodes as elements of the collection, but the error you mentioned doesn't seem related. Are you using Neo4j 3.1? Pattern comprehension was only introduced with version 3.1.

Comment: No, I'm using 3.0.3. Let me upgrade to to 3.1 in that case. Thanks!

Comment: Getting this error now. Variable `sports` not defined (line 9, column 18 (offset: 472))
"AND ALL(sport in sports WHERE (n)-[:PLAYS]->(sport))".

Comment: My fault there, I forgot to include `sports` in the WITH clauses, so it went out of scope. Fixed the queries.

Comment: For testing purposes, I only have one user that PLAYS Baseball, 3 other users with no sports relation. All 4 users lives in Ontario,Canada. No matches are returned if list of sports is passed i.e sports:['Hockey', 'Baseball']. But it works fine with just one item in list.  sports:['Baseball']. Also, is it possible to have just one sport as parameter i.e sport:'Baseball'. how will parameter comprehension work in that case ? and will this still be applicable since we don't have list of sports -  ALL(sport in sports WHERE (n)-[:PLAYS]->(sport))?

Comment: I edited my query both to handle your request for matching for any sport in the parameters (rather than only people who play all the given sports), and to fix a problem that would have prevented the query from working when no valid locations or sports are in the lists (including empty lists). Also, if you only have one sport, you will have to pass it as a list with a single member for this to work.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the new query and getting this error - Invalid input 'T': expected whitespace,..... "WHERE CASE SIZE(locations) <> 0 THEN"

Comment: My fault again, should be "WHERE CASE WHEN ". I fixed the query.

Comment: Thanks! That works. And, if I can ask you about last piece in the puzzle. Is it possible to extend the check for optional properties in Node "User". For e.g MATCH (n:User) where n.age >25 AND n.age < 35. I tried to and another CASE but it doesn't seem right. I tried adding ageMin:25, ageMax:35 to params and add another where case -  WHERE CASE WHEN params.ageMin <> 0 THEN
    MATCH (n:User) where n.age>params.ageMin AND n.age<params.ageMax
  ELSE true END

Comment: Close, but you don't need to do another MATCH. Just use `... THEN n.age > params.ageMin ...` (though you probably meant to use `>=`) You'll need to do an entirely separate CASE statement for ageMax instead of mixing them.

Comment: Thanks! really appreciate your help and time!

Comment: (regarding the deleted comment on returning null if no conditions matched): Given your other conditions, that's going to be very hard to do. The fast approach is to compare the number of results with the total count of users and use a CASE for that to return null, but the problem is that this condition either means no conditions matched, or that the conditions you gave matched all :Users. I can't think of a good way to detect the difference between these.

Comment: Yeah, it is tricky one. I guess I'll have to do some post processing in python afterwards. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I noticed that the above query doesn't work if the node doesn't exist. For e.g if I'm looking for all user in Canada and State:Alberta. If node Alberta doesn't exist then all user in Canada are returned. Is it possible to put condition on Country,State and City node that if node doesn't exist it should be treated same as no user exist in that Country or State or City?

Comment: Updated the query accordingly.

Comment: I'm still getting all the users in Canada.

Comment: Did you create the :Invalid node? That needs to exist for this to work.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. It is working now. Really appreciate your help!